# Is there a plugin for "google analytics 4" in ionic framework

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, mobile, google-analytics-4

Since July 1, 2023, will no longer send hits from universal analytics, and are there any plugins related to google analytics 4 except the react since they have a plugin for GA4?

Comment: Looking for the same.
Any news on this?

Comment: Right now I'm using firebase-x as an alternative solution for the google analytics 4 and still looking for the decent plugin which relates to GA4

Comment: Update: Using Analytics Firebase on ionic native api i successfully sending data to google analytics .

Comment: Hi Alexander, could you share the link about the Analytics Firebase?

Comment: Hi @JJ.Yuan here is the link for Analytics firebase https://ionicframework.com/docs/v5/native/analytics-firebase

Comment: @AlexanderDeMesa thx but i'm using ionic3. still cannot find a plugin for GA4.